Real-valued projection matrix on generalized eigenspace of a matrix with complex eigenvalues
Consider the Jordan decomposition $A = VJV^{-1}$. A projection matrix on the $i$-th generalized eigenspace of $A$ can be constructed as follows: construct $V_i$, whose columns are the columns of $V$ corresponding to the $i$-th Jordan block, and construct $U_i$ from the corresponding rows in $V^{-1}$, then $P_i = V_iU_i$ is a projection matrix that satisfies $m_i = \mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{im}(P_i))$, where $m_i$ is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$. Another method of constructing a projection matrix $P_i$ is using contour integration (Equation 1.7 from here).
However, in general, this results in a complex-valued projection matrix $P_i$ for complex eigenvalues. My question is, does there exist a coordinate transformation scheme that allows me to have real-valued projection matrix $P_i$? I would like to use some results from the linked paper before and having a complex-valued $P_i$ makes things much more difficult.
As a simple example, consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, which has eigenvalues $\pm i$, and the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1 = i$ is $\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. Normally, a complex-valued projection matrix on the subspace spanned by $\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ is given by
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & i \\ -i & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, if I simply constraint $P$ to be real-valued, then $P\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ if and only if $P$ is the identity, which is not very meaningful. Thus, with a $2 \times 2$ change of coordinate matrix $T = \mathrm{Re}(T) + i \mathrm{Im}(T)$ and $P = \begin{pmatrix} P_{11} & P_{12} \\ P_{21} & P_{22} \end{pmatrix}$, I solved for the elements of $T$ and $P$ (4 unknowns for each matrix, 12 in total) such that
$$
PT\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = T\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
MATLAB gives me
$$
T =
\begin{pmatrix}
   0.4085 + 0.7213i   & 0.8902 + 0.5586i \\
   0.2129 + 0.5849i   & 0.7213 + 0.5676i
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad
P = \begin{pmatrix}
    0.5748    & 0.5268 \\
    0.2504    & 0.6898
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So it seems like this direction might work in general, although I would much prefer a general formulation of projection $P$ and change of coordinates matrix $T$, especially if $A$ is large and/or has repeated eigenvalues. I am aware of the so-called "real canonical form" of a matrix, but I don't think it would help me (given the simple example above is already in real canonical form). I would appreciate any insight on this, thanks a lot!
